# 金曜日の予習に第4章を読んでおくこと, The function of こと

Tags: usage

The translation given for the sentence was "Read chapter 4 for Friday." Is the こと used just to make the sentence a bit more respectful or is it just missing some context? I feel like i'm just missing something obvious here.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [こと as an Imperative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40951/%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-as-an-imperative) / [こと (Must Do) Confusion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55596/5010)